# jQuery checkbox stays checked on-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My problem is that I when I click one of the checkboxes OFF it stays ON (Checked) visibly until a second click anywhere on the screen.

However, this is proving to be non-reproducible away from my complete webpage.  What else might be interfering? What checks/console logs might help?

On clicking ZONE2 once i get CHECKED, second click it is NOT CHECKED, however on screen the button is still highlighted. When I click on the screen elsewhere the Zone2 button becomes unhighlighted.

Styling is from the jQueryUI too

Dynamically produced HTML

```
<form id="ZoneButtonsForm">
    <span id="ButtonsetZone1">
         <input type="checkbox" id="ButtonZone1" name="zone1" checked>
         <label for="ButtonZone1">Zone 1</label>
    </span>
    <span id="ButtonsetZone2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ButtonZone2" name="zone2">
        <label for="ButtonZone2">Zone 2</label>
    </span>
    <span id="ButtonsetZone3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ButtonZone3" name="zone3">
        <label for="ButtonZone3">Zone 3</label>
    </span>                 
</form>
```

Js

```
$( "#ButtonsetZone1").buttonset({
    items: "input[type=checkbox]"
});
$( "#ButtonsetZone2").buttonset({
    items: "input[type=checkbox]"
});
$( "#ButtonsetZone3").buttonset({
    items: "input[type=checkbox]"
});


$(document).on("change", "#ZoneButtonsForm input[type=checkbox]", function () {//event delegation bind
    console.log("the zone button has been clicked");

    $( "#ButtonsetZone1").buttonset("refresh");
    $( "#ButtonsetZone2").buttonset("refresh");
    $( "#ButtonsetZone3").buttonset("refresh");

               if ($("#defIndividualButtonZone1").is(":checked")){
                    console.log("zone 1 is checked");
                }else{
                    console.log("zone 1 is NOT checked");
                }
                if ($("#defIndividualButtonZone2").is(":checked")){
                    console.log("zone 2 is checked");
                }else{
                    console.log("zone 2 is NOT checked");
                }
                if ($("#defIndividualButtonZone3").is(":checked")){
                    console.log("zone 3 is checked");
                }else{
                    console.log("zone 3 is NOT checked");
                }


});
```

Comment: Could it be that your are wiring your event handler to the document's change event, rather than the clicking of a particular checkbox and since modifying the checked state of any checkbox qualifies as changing the document, all the buttonsets get refreshed?

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/00c6uwnx/

Comment: @Scott I am using standard event delegation for dynamic content, and nothing else on the page gets reset,

Comment: @Barmar, that is the problem

Comment: Something else on your web page is interfering. The best tool for this is using `Break on attribute change` in developer tools.

Comment: @Barmar, very cool thanks, which browser you using? Cant see yet in Chrome..

Comment: Have you tried:  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click",... instead of document.onchange?

Comment: I use Chrome. Go into the Elements tab, right-click on an element, and it's the `Break on...` sub-menu.

Comment: @Scott its dynamic content, so the DOM wont find it at js runtime

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. You are using JQuery, which is just a wrapper to the DOM. If JQuery can access the elements, so can traditional DOM methods.

Comment: @Barmar, ok its a great tool but its going crazy on hover states, I will have to figure out how to use it better,,, thanks though!

Comment: @Scott, check out this about event delegation, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ its for dynamic content, content that arrives after the DOM tree is computed

Comment: Yeah, it can be noisy with jQuery UI.

Comment: I understand event delegation. I just wasn't clear on the fact that your html was not going to exist at the time your JS was running. i though the html was generated first. Sorry.

Comment: @cool, my fault, i wasnt clear enough

Comment: @Barmar, found out it was an illusion of light, the ui states of active and focus were the same colour....&*^%&^%%*&%^